# Oracle SQL Join Eror

Tags: sql, oracle, join

This is my query. But I am getting following error.

```
Select customer_info.CUSTOMER_ID, customer_info.NAME, Customer_Hierarchy_API.Get_Description(Cust_Hierarchy_Struct_API.Get_Hierarchy_Id(CUSTOMER_ID)) 
from CUST_ORD_CUSTOMER_ENT
JOIN customer_info ON 
customer_info.customer_id = cust_ord_customer_ent.customer_id;
```

> ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
> 00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"
> *Cause:
> *Action: Error at Line: 1 Column: 137

Comment: Check [this doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A64702_01/doc/server.805/a58312/newch220.htm): *Action: Prefix references to column names that exist in multiple tables with either the table name or a table alias and a period (.), as in the examples above.*

Answer (score 1):

```
Cust_Hierarchy_Struct_API.Get_Hierarchy_Id(CUSTOMER_ID)
```

You need to specify which table to take the `CUSTOMER_ID` column from, as that column name exists in two differnt tables being used *(Oracle won't do it for you, programming languages hate ambiguity, so should you)*.

In your case it doesn't matter which, but you have to choose one.

```
Cust_Hierarchy_Struct_API.Get_Hierarchy_Id(customer_info.CUSTOMER_ID)
```

As a principle, never refer to a column on its own, always fully qualify it with the table name or alias.  If when you ***can***, don't; it's sloppy and leads to problems as/when the code or database strucutre evolves.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is the `USING` clause:

```
Select ci.CUSTOMER_ID, ci.NAME, 
       Customer_Hierarchy_API.Get_Description(Cust_Hierarchy_Struct_API.Get_Hierarchy_Id(CUSTOMER_ID)) 
from CUST_ORD_CUSTOMER_ENT coc join
     customer_info ci 
     using (customer_id);
```

`USING` allows you to mention the join keys without having to qualify the reference.  After all, the value is the same regardless of which table the value comes from, based on the `JOIN` condition.